# Не приходит ответ от dnsmasq, но nslookup работает, если указать адрес сервера

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

Не приходит ответ от dnsmasq. nslookup резолвит адресс, если явно указать адрес сервера.[image: ping]

[image: nslookup]

Server config:

```
config dnsmasq 
option domainneeded '1'
option boguspriv '1'
option filterwin2k '0'
option localise_queries '1'
option rebind_protection '1'
option rebind_localhost '1'
option local '/lan/'
option domain 'lan'
option expandhosts '1'
option nonegcache '0'
option authoritative '1'
option readethers '1'
option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
option dhcpscript '/usr/sbin/dhcpinfo.sh'
```

client config:

```
log-queries
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq-queries.log
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d
interface=lo
bind-interfaces
all-servers
cache-size=1000
no-negcache
port=53
all-servers
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
```

resolv-file:

```
nameserver 10.8.0.2
nameserver 10.8.0.5
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно rebind_protection выключить или добавить домен lan в rebind_domain

```
option rebind_protection 0
```

Comment: Результата не дало

Comment: перезапусти. может ещё что, но именно эта опция ведет себя так

Comment: например, попробуй сменить домен на роутере с lan на другой

Comment: Есть еще развернутый конфиг на сервере

Comment: dhcp-authoritative
domain-needed
localise-queries
read-ethers
bogus-priv
expand-hosts
dhcp-script=/usr/sbin/dhcpinfo.sh
domain=lan
server=/lan/
dhcp-leasefile=/tmp/dhcp.leases
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto
addn-hosts=/tmp/hosts
conf-dir=/tmp/dnsmasq.d
dhcp-broadcast=tag:needs-broadcast


host-record=bad.skw.ua
,192.168.40.1


dhcp-range=lan,192.168.40.100,192.168.40.249,255.255.255.0,1
2h
dhcp-option=lan,6,8.8.8.8

Comment: Если изменить домен на роутере, то работает. Просто я хотел, чтобы домен был одинаковый на всех роутерах

Comment: И я явно указал server=/domain/ip

Comment: @Onlyoneboy если нужно быть в одном домене с апстримом - нужно делать релей дхчп для того чтоб компьютеры регистрировались в общей базе

Comment: спасибо за наводку, на стороне чего это делать ? если у меня больше 10 устройтсв. получается нужен отдельный сервер для этого ?

Comment: на стороне днс сервера домена